# Application of compactness theorem: finite exponent groups

Tags: logic, model-theory

We call $G$ a torsion group if for every $g\in G$ there exists a natural $n>0$ such that $g^n=1$. We say that $G$ has finite exponent if the inverse quantification holds, i.e. there exists a $N>0$ such that $g^N=1$ for every $g\in G$.

> Let $G$ be a torsion group, and assume that every elementary extension $G'\succ G$ is a torsion group. Show that $G$ has finite exponent using the Compactness theorem.

Any hint? I am confused because the Compactness theorem says that every finitely consistent theory is consistent, so I would find **a** model of the theory, and I cannot say if that model is actually $G$ or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument outlined below is the "generic" Compactness Theorem argument, adapted to our particular situation.

Let $L$ be the following language:

(i) $L$ has a binary function symbol (multiplication), and a constant symbol $1$.

(ii) $L$ has a constant symbol $K_g$ for every element $g$ of $G$.

(iii) $L$ has an additional constant symbol $C$.

Let $T$ be the theory over $L$ that has the following axioms:

(A) All the  sentences of $L$ that are true in $G$ when the constant symbols $K_g$ are given their natural interpretations.

(B) Sentences $C\ne 1$, $C^2\ne 1$, $C^3\ne 1$, and so on.

Suppose that $G$ does not have finite exponent. Then for any finite subset $F$ of the axioms of $T$, $F$ has a model. For any such finite set contains only finitely many of the sentences in (B). And since $G$ does not have finite exponent, there is for any $n$ an element $g$ of $G$ such that $g^k\ne 1$ for all $k$ between $1$ and $n$. If the "largest" axiom of (B) that is in $F$ is $C^n\ne 1$, then $g$ provides a suitable interpretation for $C$.

So by Compactness, if $G$ does not have finite exponent, then $T$ has a model. Any such model is (isomorphic to) an  elementary extension $G'$ of $G$. But $G'$ is not a torsion group, contradicting the assumption that every elementary extension  of $G$ is a torsion group.

Comment: Why is $G'$ elementary extension of $G$? I am trying to apply the Tarski test but it doesn't look like it's working. And in the last line, you probably mean "G' is not of torsion" rather than "G' does not have finite exponent"?

Comment: @AngeloRendina: Thank you, yes, I meant not a torsion group. Elementary extension is because that is built in by specifying in the Axioms (A) that every sentence of $L$ which (under the natural interpretation of the $K_g$) is true in $G$ is an axiom. That forces elementary extension by the definition of elementary extension.